# A question about the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I am reading the interesting [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1010818119040.pdf) written by M. Aguiar. On page 267, I don't know whether we can replace the tensor symbols in an identity by some elements such that the identity is still  established.[image]

Maybe we can ask this question by the following way. Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a commutative ring with unit and $A$ be a $\mathbf{k}$-algebra with unit. Given an identity 
$$u_1\otimes v_1=u_2\otimes v_2 \text { for some  }u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\in A.$$
If we replace  the tensor symbols by $x\in A$, the identity $$u_1x v_1=u_2x v_2$$
is still established? My question is how to prove it?

Comment: Is $\otimes$ the tensor product over $A$, i.e. $\otimes = \otimes_A$, or the tensor product over some fixed ground field (or commutative ground ring) $k$ (for which $A$ is a $k$-algebra)?

Comment: @ Jendrik Stelzner , thank you for your commute, I have edited my queation.

Comment: @ Jendrik Stelzner, it is over $\mathbf{k}$, I think it is no use to define  $\otimes$ over an algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\otimes$ denotes the tensor product over $\mathbf{k}$, so that $\otimes = \otimes_\mathbf{k}$.

**To answer the question as stated:**
The map
$$
          A \times A
  \to     A,
  \quad   (u,v)
  \mapsto uxv
$$
is $\mathbf{k}$-bilinear, and thus induces a $\mathbf{k}$-linear map
$$
          h
  \colon  A \otimes_\mathbf{k} A
  \to     A,
  \quad   u \otimes v
  \mapsto uxv.
$$
It then follows for $\sum_i u_i \otimes v_i = \sum_j u'_j \otimes v'_j$ and $x \in A$ that
$$
    \sum_i u_i x v_i
  = h\left( \sum_i u_i \otimes v_i \right)
  = h\left( \sum_j u'_j \otimes v'_j \right)
  = \sum_j u'_j x v'_j.
$$

**But** I think we actually want that for $\sum_i u_i \otimes v_i \otimes w_i = \sum_j u'_j \otimes v'_j \otimes w'_j$ and $x, y \in A$ we have that
$$
    \sum_i u_i x v_i y w_i
  = \sum_j u'_j x v'_j y w'_j.
$$
This can be shown in the same way as above by considering the $\mathbf{k}$-trilinear map
$$
          A \times A \times A
  \to     A,
  \quad   (u,v,w)
  \mapsto uxvyw.
$$
For $r = \sum_i u_i \otimes v_i$ and $\beta \colon A \to A$ given by $\beta(x) = \sum_i u_i x v_i$ we have that
\begin{align*}
      \beta(x)\beta(y)
  &=  \sum_{i,j} u_i x v_i u_j y v_j, \\
      \beta(\beta(x) y)
  &=  \sum_{i,j} u_i u_j x v_j y v_i, \\
      \beta(x \beta(y))
  &=  \sum_{i,j} u_j x u_i y v_i v_j,
\end{align*}
so it then follows with $\mathbf{A}(r) = 0$ (by replacing the tensor symbols $\otimes$ in the given equation by $x$ and $y$) that
$$
    \beta(x)\beta(y)
  = \beta(\beta(x) y) + \beta(x \beta(y)).
$$
From what I understand, this is what it means for $\beta$ to be a Baxter operator.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Thank you very much. I worry $x$ can be annihilated by $u_1$. By your answer, this can not appear.

Comment: It could happen that $u_1$ annihilates $x$, and thus $u_1 x v_1 = 0$. But for $u_1 \otimes v_1 = u_2 \otimes v_2$ it then follows that also $u_2 x v_2 = 0$ because of the equality $u_1 x v_1 = u_2 x v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure because your binary operation on $A$
$\cdot: AxA\to A$ is a balanced product   and so, by universal property of tensor product, there exists a unique map $\phi:A\otimes A\to A$ such that $\cdot=\phi\circ\otimes$ and so if you have that $u_1\otimes v_1=u_2\otimes v_2$ than $u_1v_1=\phi\circ\otimes (u_1,v_1)=\phi(u_1\otimes v_1)=$
$\phi(u_2\otimes v_2)= \phi\circ\otimes(u_2, v_2) =u_2v_2$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know whether the identity $u_1xv_1=u_2xv_2$ is still established? Is it the same?